# Accessing Q_Properties of a class inherited from an Object that inherited from QObject

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qproperty

I have the following simplified setup where I'm trying to access the Q_Properties on the **inherited** class of a class that inherits from QObject. I can access the properties of the base class just fine but I can't find or see (while debugging) the properties of my inherited class:

**Base Class:**

```
class Vehicle : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(QString model READ getModel WRITE setModel)      
public:
   explicit Vehicle(QObject *parent = 0);
   QString getModel() const;      
   void setModel(QString model);
   virtual QString toString() const;
private:
    QString _model;
};
```

**Inherited Class:**

```
class TransportVehicle : public Vehicle
{
    Q_PROPERTY(int Capacity READ getCapacity WRITE setCapacity)

public:
    TransportVehicle();
    TransportVehicle(int, QString, int);
    int getCapacity() const;
    void setCapacity(int);

    QString toString() const;
private:
    int _maxCapacity;
};
```

and the following snippet from a generic method to access the properties of which ever object it finds in the list that is passed to it:

```
int write(QObjectList* list) {
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++)
{
    const QMetaObject *mo = list->at(i)->metaObject();
    for(int k = mo->propertyOffset(); k < mo->propertyCount(); k++)
    {
        const QMetaProperty prop = mo->property(k);
        QString name = prop.name();
        QString valStr = prop.read(list->at(i)).toString();
        QDebug << name << ": " << valStr << endl; 
        count++;
    }
    delete mo;
}
return count;
}
```

It works fine except my output will be like 'model: toyota' and won't include capacity.

The only way I've been able to get the properties of my subclasses is to add virtual get and set methods and an additional Q_property to my base class, which doesn't seem right at all and not possible in normal circumstances where I don't have access to the base class.

Comment: Why are you deleting mo?

Comment: @ddriver I did it while unsure, I thought since it's a pointer, since it's being redeclared in each iteration that I should clean up? Or is this unneeded completely because of it being a QObject?

Comment: Don't delete it, you are walking into undefined behavior. The pointer returned simply points to the meta object, it is not allocated dynamically and should not be deleted.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vehicle` inherits `QObject`, so `TransportVehicle` will have to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro, `Q_GADGET` is when you don't inherit `QObject` and want a meta object.

Every class which directly on indirectly inherits `QObject` needs the `Q_OBJECT` macro. You don't have it in `TransportVehicle` so you don't get meta data generated for it, you are stuck with the meta object that was generated for the base class.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that initially but get a "undefined reference to 'vtable for TransportVehicle' error. 
Which as far as I remember, is a similar error like when trying to use Template classes, the inheriting class must be declared in the same file as the base class right? So is that the same case with QObject?

I've tried it and it works but is that the only way? Or can one use something like forward class declarations rather?

Comment: @topher - try clean all, run qmake and rebuild all from the build menu

Comment: Awesome thanks that got it! Can't believe I spent hours on this because I needed to rebuild :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing use of macro `Q_OBJECT`:

```
class TransportVehicle : public Vehicle
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ^^^^^^^^
    Q_PROPERTY(int Capacity READ getCapacity WRITE setCapacity)

public:
    TransportVehicle();
    TransportVehicle(int, QString, int);
    int getCapacity() const;
    void setCapacity(int);

    QString toString() const;
private:
    int _maxCapacity;
};
```

For documentation please see : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

Comment: I've added Q_GADGET, but it does the same, however I see the staticMetaObject as mentioned in the docs, but from looking at that while debugging I still only see the model property... any idea?

Comment: This is wrong, `Q_GADGET` is for when you want meta data but don't inherit `QObject`.